# get the key of current function in associated array

Tags: javascript

If I have the following array with a key for a function

```
var a = {};
a["first"] = function() {};
```

Is it possible to get the name of key which associate with this function and use it
in the function?

Comment: fyi  It is not an array. It is object literal and you are using bracket notation.

Comment: `a.first = a.second = a.third = unrelatedVariable = function() {}`  Now what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, using only code within the function and not referring to anything outside it, it's impossible for the function to know that it was retrieved from that property of that object in the general case.

You can get close, though, if we make some big assumptions. Assuming the function is called as part of the same expression that retrieves its value (e.g., `a["first"]()` or `a.first()`), and assuming it's called in the normal way, then within the function `this` will refer to `a`. But there's still no way for the function to figure out which property on `this` (`a`) refers to it without resorting to `arguments.callee`, which is very bad practice and deprecated. And which can't differentiate between various scenarios (including multiple properties on `a` referring to the same function).

**If** you're okay with bad practice and code that is unlikely to work in engines in the future, then:

```
var a = {};
a["first"] = function() {
    var thisFunction = arguments.callee; // **BAD PRACTICE** **DEPRECATED**
    var key;
    for (key in this) {
        if (this[key] === thisFunction) {
            console.log("This function MAY have been called via the " + key + " property");
        }
    }
};
a["first"]();
```

...but there's no guarantee that it wasn't:

```
var f = a.first;
f.call(a);
```

...or

```
var a = {};
a["first"] = function() {
   // ...see above...
};
a["second"] = a["first"];
a["third"] = a["first"];
// ...and so on...
a["fourteenth"]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only code within the function and not referring to anything outside it, it's **possible** of course.

JavaScript it's a tricks ))

```
var a = {};

a["first"] = function() {

    var getArgs = function(){return this.arguments};

    for(var i in this){

        if(typeof this[i] === 'function' && getArgs.call(this[i]) === arguments){
            console.log("my name is " + i);
        }
    }

};

a["second"] = function() {console.log('Eh?')};

a["first"]();
a["second"]();
```